# ATOM PHP linter without php installed

Tags: php, atom-editor, linter

I'm looking for an **alternative way** to use PHP-Linter on ATOM.

I have a computer with ATOM, and a Vagrant and inside a PHP Docker Container.
of course I can map my Docker PHP to Vagrant then to my Host but im looking for an alternative.

Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you download PHP and add the executable to ATOM without running it? Or is there a reason not to have that on your system

Comment: No the main issue is that we have no installation rights on our computers, and process with admins takes ages, so this is why I use vagrant and I cant really install php in the Host. its a really specific environnent.